# Photoshop CS6 Image Import

Tags: image, import, photoshop

Could not place the document ‘GeniusButton_1only_.png’ because the file-format module cannot parse the file. I need to know how to fix this problem I can import pictures fine if they are saved from the internet but when I pull them off of my iPhone and try to edit them with Photoshop I get that error. I'm on Mac dragging the image from my desktop into Photoshop it worked fine before until now.

Comment: what are you trying to do? What steps did you go through which don't seem to work? Import to what, Photoshop, a program you made? What does the iphone have to do with this? What is 'GeniusButton_1only_.png?' what is the file-format module? Why can't it parse the file? I have no idea what you are asking, I assume others are also confused, please elaborate further, or no one will help you, simply because they don't understand how to help...

Comment: That image is a iPhone,iPod,iPad image for the music player. I drag and drop into photoshop and I get that error I right click the image and choose open with photoshop and I get that error. If I knew what the iPhone had to do with this I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: do you mean cover art?

Comment: also, is this related to programming?

Comment: By the way, it's not a problem, we all need to learn somehow, everyone just wants to help...

Comment: It's not a cover art and it's not related to programing it's related to theming/graphic design

Comment: By the way, sorry if I sounded like kind of a douche when I asked to questions, I didn't mean to offend you if I did... However where are you dragging in this image from?

Comment: I'm on Mac dragging the image from my desktop into Photoshop it worked fine before until now.

Comment: Is it possible the image is corrupt, have you tried with another image, also I've seen mac mess with files in their own way, I noticed it added some stuff to a zip file when I decompressed it through the terminal, I guess it's possible here that it messed with it just enough, also considering this isn't a programming question, maybe try to get a mod to move it to another stackexchange site. You might get more luck

Comment: Also add this info to your question so that 1) I can remove my downvote and 2) so others don't need you read our conversation in order to understand your question...

Comment: Sorry, I asked if other images work, I just reread your question...

Comment: Alright, so can you open the png in other programs like preview, it could just be an unfortunate case of a corrupt image

Comment: Yea Preview works fine

Comment: Working on an answer...

Comment: OK and I appreciate your help this is frustrating me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like your image is not working with photoshop**

However, you say it works fine with the Mac OS X image viewing software, Preview...

Therefore, we can make the following assumptions:

- The image is not corrupt, (except to Photoshop, but that's okay because that is one program, not all of them)
- Photoshop, in this situation is not working with this particular image file...

Now, if Photoshop is refusing to work with one particular image the best solution is to make a new one with the same content. That's easy:

I looked up how to duplicate an image/change the format in preview and found this:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/29/save-images-as-gif-other-formats-preview-mac-os-x/

To summarize: <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Save As</kbd>

You can either go with a PNG or Photoshop format which I think I spotted there...

Hope this helps, and sorry if I insulted you in any way, I just wanted to help... I did not want to judge you in any way

Anyway good luck

-- Luke

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot I may just restore my phone rejailbreak and before installing the theming app WinterBoard I'll copy all the apps back to my Mac

Comment: Thanks and just to let you know you never insulted me so your good on that part

Comment: Okay great, glad I could help =D

Comment: I found a better solution I decided to use iFunBox instead of Filezilla and it works that way

Comment: Sweet, so filezilla was the problem!